# Wordpress permalinks redirect to the homepage in Lighttpd

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, raspberry-pi, lighttpd, permalinks

I have this Wordpress app live on my Raspberry Pi with Lighttpd. I have activated the permalink option in the admin with this pattern `http://www.myurl.com/index.php/%category%/%postname%/` but when I click to the link to see a  post or any other pages (static pages, categories), I'm redirected to the homepage.

Is there any additionnal rules to set up in Lighttpd? As far as I understand, there is only if I want to have clean URL without `/index.php/`.

Of course, links such as `http://www.myurl.com/?p=X` work perfectly fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: The same thing happened to me a few days ago. All I had to do to fix it was to disable all the plugins I had enabled then reenable them, then disable them a second time and then reenable them and it all worked for me.

Comment: I had indeed to disable the `Rewrite` plugin even though I hadn't set up any rewrite rule. Now the permalink work fine, I just need to figure out how to make the `/index.php/` disapear from my URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, I had to disable the "Rewrite" plugin (I downloaded it before knowing about the permalinks anyway). I have also managed to have URL without `/index.php/` by configuring `/%category%/%postname%/` in the `Permalinks` section of Wp-Admin and by having these rules in my `lighttpd.conf`:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/wiki/.*" => "$0",
     "^/(.*/)?files/$" => "/index.php",
     "^/(.*/)?files/(.*)" => "/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2",
     "^(/wp-admin/.*)" => "$1",
     "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*)" => "/$2",
     "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)" => "/$2",
     "^/(.*)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
 )
```